# Best way to electrochemically etch metal

Tags: electrochemistry

I've got some plates of cast iron that I'd like to etch electrically  in a pattern by masking certain portions, as is commonly done for chemical etch.  I found several sources all indicating that the metal to be etched should be positive with respect to the counterelectrode.  So I hooked up about 3VDC to the work piece to be etched and negative terminal to the counterelectrode, all submerged in a saltwater bath. This voltage sufficed for about 10 amps for the ~ 5cm^2 pieces I am testing. When I do this  I get bubbling off the counterelectrode, and none off the work piece.  Is this to be expected? I was imagining that the active bubbling was the etching occurring in which case I'd want to put the counterelectrode positive w.r.t the work piece.
In any case will adding some acid eg. 10% HCl speed things up? I need to get thru 3mm iron.

Comment: drive-by downvotes are so annoying - at least state what you think is missing

Comment: I have down-voted, because 1. I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, i.e. do you just want to dissolve the iron 2. there is not enough detail about the actual conditions to count as a chemical experiment, 3. "best" implies that you are asking for an opinion as no rigid criteria are given 4. the question is better suited somewhere else, maybe [diy.se] 5. There is little to no actual evidence that you did do some research on what you are trying to attempt.

Comment: Flake type ( grey) or other types of cast iron ? The graphite flakes may have a effect ; there are some ordinary corrosion situations where the iron is removed leaving a surface of mostly flake graphite, ( "graphitic corrosion").

Comment: The question is really in need of an answer. Chemical expectations are that bubbling = a reaction, therefore, no bubbling = no reaction. This especially affects non-chemists, who add NaHCO3 to vinegar to clean sinks and such. We need to explain how the absence of bubbling can still cover a rapid reaction or useful chemical effects - or how bubbling is a positive indication but no bubbling is not proof of inactivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bubbling off the (negative) electrode is hydrogen being evolved as sodium cation is drawn to that electrode. Your electrolyte also has a negative chloride ion (anion) which is being drawn to the (positive) cast iron piece, but instead of evolving as Cl$_2$ or even O$_2$, it attacks the cast iron and dissolves it as Fe$^{+2}$. Instead of extracting electrons from the anion, the process is extracting electrons from the iron atoms in the cast iron and putting these iron cations into solution - you should see a slight color change.

So, consider that the bubbling at the cathode represents a certain amount of reaction which is happening invisibly also at the anode. If you hook an ammeter in series with your circuit, you can determine the rate of iron dissolution.

In my experience, electrolysis is good for electropolishing or for small amounts of reaction, but 3 mm of iron is going to take a long time, depending on the area involved. I would suggest using hydrochloric acid to start, perhaps tempered with urea. Cleaning and etching solutions are commercially available, or you can make your own from urea and muriatic acid (https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/b3/b3dfe4ac-18ae-40c1-be18-81d192a75709.pdf). After you get about 2.5 mm etched off, you can swith to electrolysis if you like.

Comment: Please don't use MathJax this way: `Cl$_2$`. It has the potential to completely break on other screens than yours and after updates and changes. Either use `\ce{Cl2}` (preferred) or `Cl<sub>2</sub>`.